# Functions parameter not working inside a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

Im using Vue js and Firebase for an application. I create a function for retrieve monthly expense.

```
totalExpenseByType(){
        db.collection('expenses').where("created_month", "==", moment().format('MM-YYYY'))

        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
              var totalExpensesOfThisMonth = 0;
              snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                 totalExpensesOfThisMonth += Number(doc.data().expense_amount)
              })
              this.expenses_of_this_month = totalExpensesOfThisMonth;

         })
         return this.expenses_of_this_month;
      }
```

**This works perfectly.**

But I add a parameter a where condition. It behaves strangely. It return unstoppable loop that repeat all the data.

```
  totalExpenseByType(expense_type){
    db.collection('expenses').where("created_month", "==", moment().format('MM-YYYY'))
                             .where("expense_type", "==", {"expense_type": expense_type})
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
          var totalExpensesOfThisMonth = 0;
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
             totalExpensesOfThisMonth += Number(doc.data().expense_amount)
          })
          this.expenses_of_this_month = totalExpensesOfThisMonth;

     })
     return this.expenses_of_this_month;
  }
```

and this is the code I use for display data

```
  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.expense_type }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ totalExpenseByType(props.item.expense_type) }}</td>
            <v-btn fab dark small color="pink" @click="removeExepenseType(props.item.id)">
               <v-icon dark>remove</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
  </template>
```

**Data Structure**

```
created_month: "09-2018"
expense_amount: "600"
expense_title:"Employee Salary"   
expense_type:"Employee Expense"    
timestamp:1536126964353
```

Answer (score 1):

*Update following your latest update about your data structure...:*

Do as I originally advised:

```
totalExpenseByType(expense_type){
       db.collection('expenses')
       .where("created_month", "==", moment().format('MM-YYYY'))
       .where("expense_type", "==", expense_type)
       .get()
        .....
```

Then, you have another problem. The `get()` method is asynchronous and returns a promise, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get). By doing

```
totalExpenseByType(){
        db.collection('expenses').where("created_month", "==", moment().format('MM-YYYY'))

        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
              var totalExpensesOfThisMonth = 0;
              snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                 totalExpensesOfThisMonth += Number(doc.data().expense_amount)
              })
              this.expenses_of_this_month = totalExpensesOfThisMonth;

         })
         return this.expenses_of_this_month;
      }
```

you are returning the value of `this.expenses_of_this_month` before the promise has resolved and therefore it does not return the correct value.

In addition I think you are misunderstanding the Vue’s reactivity system: in your code, you are (if I am correct assuming that `this` is your Vue instance) assigning the value of `totalExpensesOfThisMonth` to the `expenses_of_this_month` property of your component's `data` object AND  returning, in your `totalExpenseByType(expense_type)` function, the same `data` object property (incorrectly, see above).

---

*Update following your last comment below: is a string with value "expense_type:"Employee Expense"*

Since you mentioned that it is a string with value "expense_type:"Employee Expense" you should do as follows:

```
db.collection("test").where("expense_type", "==", '"expense_type:"Employee Expense"').get().then()
```

or, if the external double quotes are to be removed:

```
db.collection("test").where("expense_type", "==", 'expense_type:"Employee Expense').get().then()
```

---

*Update following your update about your data structure:*

If I understand correctly, you are storing `expense_type` as an object.

In this case, your query should be as follows:

```
db.collection('expenses').where("expense_type.expense_type", "==", "Employee Expense").get().then()
```

---

*Previous answer, to be discarded*

I think it should be as follows:

```
totalExpenseByType(expense_type){
   db.collection('expenses')
   .where("created_month", "==", moment().format('MM-YYYY'))
   .where("expense_type", "==", expense_type)
   .get()
    .....
```

unless `expense_type` field is of type Array. In this case you should use the "Array membership" syntax, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership

Comment: no that is not the problem. I have to use like this {"expense_type": expense_type} coz data structure is like this

Comment: Could you share your data structure, by adding it to your original question

Comment: Could you be more precise please: is expense_type of type object? Or it is a string with value "expense_type:"Employee Expense" ?

Comment: is a string with value "expense_type:"Employee Expense"

Comment: Then do `db.collection("test").where("expense_type", "==", '"expense_type:"Employee Expense"').get().then()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: hi please check Data Structure. now expense type is a simple string. not an array.  The problem is here <td class="text-xs-left">{{ totalExpenseByType(props.item.expense_type) }}</td> . If I use totalExpenseByType("Office Expense") }} then It works. but when I pass a variable on the parameter, it not working :(